# PowerShell grep quivalent

Tags: bash, powershell, grep

I am trying to port this command line from bash to PowerShell:

```
git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | grep -v chain | sort -k3nr | head
```

So far I have this:

```
git verify-pack -v (Get-ChildItem ".git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx") | select-string -pattern "chain"
```

But how do I do an invert match in PowerShell (option **-v** to [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep))?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean `-NotMatch`?

```
Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern "chain"
```

[Select-String @ Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx)